# Testing Regex in If, Else Statement

Tags: ruby, regex

I think I'm close, but the regex isn't evaluating.  Hoping someone may know why.

```
def new_title(title)
  words = title.split(' ')
  words = [words[0].capitalize] + words[1..-1].map do |w|
    if w =~ /and|an|a|the|in|if|of/
      w
    else
      w.capitalize
    end
  end
  words.join(' ')
end
```

When I pass in lowercase titles, they get returned as lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to properly anchor your regular expression:

```
new_title("the last hope")
# => "The last Hope"
```

This is because `/a/` matches a word with an `a` in it. `/\Aa\Z/` matches a string that consists entirely of `a`, and `/\A(a|of|...)\Z/` matches against a set of words.

In any case, what you might want is this:

```
case (w)
when 'and', 'an', 'a', 'the', 'in', 'if', 'of'
  w
else
  w.capitalize
end
```

Using a regular expression here is a bit heavy handed. What you want is an exclusion list.

Answer (score 1):

This is called titleize, and is implemented like this:

```
def titleize(word)
  humanize(underscore(word)).gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
end
```

[Se the doc.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize)

If you want fancy titlezing, check out [granth's titleize](https://github.com/granth/titleize)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression should be checking the whole word (`^word$`). Anyway, isn't more simple to use `Enumerable#include?`:

```
def new_title(title)
  words = title.split(' ')
  rest_words = words.drop(1).map do |word|
    %w(and an a the in if of).include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize
  end
  ([words[0].capitalize] + rest_words).join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Yeah, include is definitely what I'd normally do, but I was doing a bit of practice with regular expressions.